# React Native: Image doesn't show in the view

Tags: javascript, image, typescript, react-native, components

sorry if I am reposting a question but I can't find one that would explain this.

My render() function returns this in my React Native application.

```
<View style={styles.login_card_view}>

    <Text>aaa</Text>
    <Image source={require('./logo_full.png')} style={{width: 200, height: 40}}/>
    <Text>bbb</Text>

    <Card>
        ...
    </Card>

    <Button containerStyle={{ marginTop: 20, alignItems: 'center', flex: 1}} />
</View>
```

This only results in an empty space for the image. (Image is in the same place as my class component.) Image doesn't show in that space but two of my texts 'aaa' and 'bbb' has a difference of 40. (That is the given height for the image.)

Am I using the Image component wrong? This is exactly similar to the documentation. Any help appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: From the information, you provided I don't see anything wrong, but some props, styles, other things which not shown in question can effect. It would be really easy to help you if you can share your issue with https://snack.expo.io/

Comment: Hi, this is the login page from me https://snack.expo.io/@buddhiv/mad-hummus?session_id=snack-session-By-6659D7, this gives the error in my application but in the snack it is working. In my local expo instance it is not working. Can there be any other dependent reasons for that?

Comment: are you using same expo version? did you try it in the root component?

Comment: No it is not rendered even in the main App.js. I suspect that this is something wrong with bundling. Doesn't expo bundle for us when it is serving the application?

Comment: @buddiv did you try to add another image?

Comment: yeah, all images are facing the same issue unfortunately

Comment: Then defently something wrong with your expo installation. Default suggestion to try reinstall it.

Comment: okay i ll try that too. Will post here what happened on reinstalling

Answer (score -1):

```
import {View,StyleSheet, Text , Button , Image} from 'react-native';
import React , {Component} from 'react';
export default class BasicExample extends React.Component{
    render (){
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>aaa</Text>
                <Image source={require('./logo_full.png')} style={{width: 200, height:   40}}/>
                <Text>bbb</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }

  }
```

I run this code and it works for me. remember to put image location and name correctly. your code may have error like button without 
title.

Comment: For me it is not working, My Button cannot have wrong properties because all other things work in the screen. I wonder something is required to show the image but not mentioned in the docs or anywhere I have reinstalled require.js again too.

Comment: Image source is also correct. Otherwise it will give an error saying the image is not  found in the path.

Answer (score -2):

I think if you use like this

```
 <Image source={require('/logo_full.png')} style={{width: 200, height: 40}}/>
```

it can be work.